# 'QuerySet' object doesn't support item deletion Error

Tags: python, django

I am trying to delete an Item in the QuerySet by Index. I am able to display the items of the QuerySet using `print q_set[code_id - 1]` but can not delete it using `del q_set[code_id - 1]`. I want to permanently delete the item and not filter excluding that item.

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError at /lessons/customcode/5/delete

'QuerySet' object doesn't support item deletion
```

views.py

```
...
    def customcode_view(request):
        global q_set
        try:
            u = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
        except:
            return render(request,"login_required.html",{})

        q_set = customcode.objects.filter(user=u)


        if request.method == "POST":
            form = CustomcodeForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cc = form.save(commit=False)
                cc.user = u
                cc.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('#BOTTOM')
        else:
            form = CustomcodeForm()

        return render(request, "customcode.html" , {'q_set':q_set,'form':form,})


    def deletecode(request,code_id):
        code_id = int(code_id)
        del q_set[code_id - 1] #this is the problem
        return redirect('customcode_view')

...
```

models.py

```
...

    class customcode(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        name = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=250)
        sourcecode = models.TextField(blank=False)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
...
```

Comment: Do you want to delete it from the queryset or from the database?

Comment: +1 I assumed he wanted it gone from the db just based on the phrasing "I want to permanently delete the item and not filter excluding that item", but that might have been premature o.O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *permanently* get rid of the entry, you don't want to remove the item from the queryset (which is just a volatile view onto your data), but [delete the row](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#deleting-objects) from the database:

```
q_set[code_id - 1].delete()
```

Hth
dtk

Comment: this gave me error:` 'customcode' object has no attribute 'remove'`

Comment: Can you make sure you called `delete()` and not `remove()`?

Comment: It worked!... sorry for the comment, i used remove() by mistake

Comment: Great. If this indeed does what you want (i.e. permanently modify the db), it'd be great if you accepted the answer. You might also want to take a look at [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for coding conventions. At the very least, your class name wants to start with an uppercase letter ;) Stay curious.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get rid of the entry in your list but not of the row in your database try the following:

```
help = q_set[:]
q_set = q_set[:code_id - 1]
q_set.append(help[code_id:])
```

Answer (score 0):

first convert queryset to list if you  want to use as a list

```
q_set_list=list(q_set)
```